# unlink() function not working with variables?

Tags: php, var, unlink

Im having some troubles unlinking files from a directory. I'll try to explain it as good as i can.

Im trying to delete a file from a directory, first i get the file name from my database, where is stored in field "avatar".

these are my involved vars:

```
$avatar1=mysqli_query($con,"Select avatar from users where user='$_SESSION[Username]'");
$avatar2=mysqli_fetch_array($avatar1);
$avatardirectory = $avatar2['avatar']; //(missunderstanding name, its actually a file).
```

So far, when i print `$avatardirectory` when my user is hodor, it shows "hodor.png"

Ok, here comes the nasty part, i try to go with this:

```
unlink('/var/www/html/test/img-gallery/$avatardirectory'); //This wont work.
```

Then I just do the same exact thing but with filename:

```
unlink('/var/www/html/prueba/img-gallery/hodor.png'); //This actually works.
```

And now I'm totally lost.

Comment: Variable interpolation does not work in single quoted strings. Use an IDE with syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables arn't expanded inside single quote strings.

You might want to see the difference in

```
 echo '/var/www/html/test/img-gallery/$avatardirectory'
```

and

```
 echo "/var/www/html/test/img-gallery/$avatardirectory"
```

Note that unlink() removes files, not directories. use rmdir() to remove (an empty) directory. (though it sounds like your $avatardirectory holds the name of a file, not a directory(?) )

Comment: Thanks nos! yes my var names trend to be messy to other people, my bad. Now it's fully working.